# How do I make a constructor for a BST Node?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Do I need to make another class? e.g. Person?

Sorry my programing skills are rusty.

```
public class Node 
{
    Node left;
    Node right;
    Node parent;
    String name;
    String DoB;
    int phoneNumber;

....

}

public class BST {
    Node root;
    int size;
    
...
}
```

Comment: Seems good to me, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can implement directly like this:

```
public class BSTNode {

    BSTNode left;
    BSTNode right;
    BSTNode parent;
    String name;
    String DoB;
    int phoneNumber;

....

}
```

// to initialize

```
BSTNode() {}
```

// if there is only a single node

```
   BSTNode(String name, String DoB, int phoneNumber) {
   this.name=name;
   this.DoB=Dob;
   this.phoneNumber=phoneNumber;
   }
```

//if bst contains more than one node

```
BSTNode(String name, String DoB, int phoneNumber,BSTNode parent,BSTNode 
left,BSTNode right){
     this.parent=parent;
     this.left=left;
     this.right=right;
     this.name=name;
     this.DoB=Dob;
     this.phoneNumber=phoneNumber;
     }
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot about the String key which is a combination of name+DoB. Do I need to put it in the Node constructer or just in the BST Class?

Comment: You have to put it in a class, as it is a member variable, and also pass it in the constructor the way we are passing name, dob.. similarly.